# whats wrong with my django url in this basic search function?

Tags: python, django, url-routing

I tried implementing a search bar in my nav bar that sends a GET request with parameters to `/search`.  When I type something into the search bar and hit enter it just takes me to `/search/` with a 404 error.

Same if I manually type `/search/?searchstring=32423` I also get a page not found.

views.py

```
def basic_search(request):
    query = request.GET.get('searchstring')
    if query:
        context={"query": query}
        return render(request, 'root_index.html', context)
    else:
        return redirect('/')
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^search/$', views.basic_search,)
```

in my base.html

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search" name="searchstring" action="/search/" method="get">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="Search">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
          </button>
        </form>
```

Comment: What is `if float(query):` meant to do? Note it could raise a type error for certain values.

Comment: trying to figure out if the search query is a number

Comment: But that just tries to convert it to a float, which as I said could cause errors. You don’t really want values like `'2.65'`, so it would be better to use `query.isdigit()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first url pattern fails to match because it’s missing the trailing slash. Change it the regex to:

```
r'^search/$'
```

The second url pattern will never match anything, because the dollar (which matches end of string) is in the middle. You shouldn’t include the querystring in the regex, therefore you should just remove this pattern.

You have a function based view, so you should use `request.GET` to access the get params, not `self.request.GET`.

Comment: I made these edits and I now get a 400 instead of 404 error on /search/%searchstring=5,  I'm guessing this means my form and urls are correct but I need to fix my views

Comment: The form should have `action="/search/"` to match the URL pattern. Redirecting to `/search/searchstring=%s/%s` is odd. Usually you would render a template and show the results. See the example from the [Django forms chapter](https://djangobook.com/django-forms/) of The Django Book.

Comment: yes I have updated the OP to show the changes I have made, I still get 400 errors

Comment: It is the `input` that should have `name="searchstring"`, not the `form`. However I don't know why you're getting a 400 error.

Comment: at least now i see when i type a search string and hit enter it is passing searchstring as param in url so that's good, but still 404 error.

Comment: Which URL do you get the 404 for?

Comment: /search/?searchstring=324

Comment: But `/search/` doesn't give a 404? I can't explain why you'd get that behaviour.

Comment: /search/ also gives 404

Comment: Did you change the url pattern to `url(r'^search/$', views.basic_search,),` as I suggested in the answer above? Are those URL patterns in the project's URLs, or included in another URL config?

Comment: I forgot to update OP, but yes I did change it, it is in the project's URLs

Comment: Perhaps you haven't saved your file or restarted your server after making the changes.